# Blackmagic raw video files in blender

Tags: video

Is it possible to import Blackmagic .braw video files into Blender?
Blackmagic have released .braw with an SDK for anyone to incorporate .braw into programs for free.

Someone has written a Lightwave 3D file to import them into Lightwave.

It would probably be better to process files in Davinci Resolve and then import the files to be processed in Blender, but on occasion direct imports would save time and space.